# is numpy isclose function returning bad answer?

Tags: python, numpy

Using numpy isclose in the following example:

```
import numpy as np
np.isclose(1533761040,1533748023.0, atol=1)
```

Returns True, which is False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it uses both an absolute and relative tolerance, and the default of rtol is nonzero, adding some more tolerance. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Comment: that's great, I thought it only uses rtol or atol, thanks for your explanation!